# Q: how do I show, update, edit user profile by username in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a custom authentication guard `Applicant` and already have created `ApplicantsProfile` model.

Problem 1 :

so far i am stuck with the show method, it is working but whatever `ID` i passed to the route it renders the view .

Problem 2 :

I want to access each applicant profile by it's `ID`

Problem 3 :

How do edit and update the authenticated user profile?

`Profile Model`

```
class ApplicantsProfile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'job_title', 'applicant_id',
    ];

    public function applicant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Applicant::class);
    }
}
```

`Profile Controller`

```
class ApplicantsProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:applicant');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
       $profile = ApplicantsProfile::find($id);

       return view('applicant.profile', compact('profile'));
    }
}
```

`Profile View`

```
@extends('layouts.auth')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">{{Auth::guard('applicant')->user()->name}}</div>

        <div class="card-body">
          {{Auth::guard('applicant')->user()->profile->job_title}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

`Route`

```
Route::get('/account/{profile}', 'ApplicantsProfileController@show');
```

If I go to route: account/1 or account/2 it renders the view of the authenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

in your profile view, you use `Auth` so it's normal to show these results.
you have to modify your view blade to something like :

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            {{ $applicantsProfile['name'] }}
        </div>
        <!-- complete your code like so -->
```

in your controller you have to do something like:

```
 public function show(ApplicantsProfile $applicantsProfile)
    {
       return view('applicant.profile', compact('applicantsProfile'));
    }
```

and in your web.php route:

```
Route::get('/account/{applicantsProfile}', 'ApplicantsProfileController@show');
```

Comment: It works, but what about accessing the email address related to the user table? or is it a better approach to store all user information in the User model instead of having a separate model in my case `ApplicantsProfile` ?

Comment: it depends on your application no absolute answer for all applications, but my advice to keep it simple as possible. if the User model will be enough for your application so no need for extra

Comment: Indeed, Thank you :)